# File.isFile() returns false while trying to create a file in android from local drive

Tags: java, android

I tried creating a pdf file into my device out of a file in my local drive. But File.isFile() method returns false.It returns true if i compile the program as a simple java file. Is tht android would not locate a file in the local by reading the path or I/o operations in android are totally different to java i/o.How to make android recognise the file in the path mentioned. Any suggestions?

```
String path = "D:\\priya_Docs\\Android pdfs\\Professional_Android_Application_Development.pdf";
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println("Located a file " + file.isFile());
        String filesArray = file.getPath();
        File getFile = file.getAbsoluteFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = (FileOutputStream) openFileOutput(
                "Androiddoc.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        System.out.println("File Created");
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buff)) >= 0) {
            fos.write(buff, 0, len);
        }

        fis.close();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: What are the exact paths you are using?  `isFile` is not a static method.  What is your actual `File` object pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You android device (emulator or phone alike) cannot access you local drive.

It can only access its own system, and generally you can access only some of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Check using .exists like     `if(myFile.exists())`

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your code, so I have to guess. I surmise you are doing `File.isFile("/non/existant/path/file.pdf");`. In that case, `isFile()` will return false, ofcourse.